# OnClick load Array in other JAVA file Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, onclick

I'm busy making an android app in java and xml. It's a sort of puzzle game, a bit similar to sudoku.

So i have a scrollview, with a table layout inside it. I have more tablerows than in this code, but showing them too would be unnecessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
>      

<TableLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"

         >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/game1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

        />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
         >

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/game2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I use this code to get to an other activity if i click on the tablerow.

```
TableRow game1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
    game1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Game1.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
TableRow game2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
    game2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Game2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });
```

Now i have for each game an other activity, but the only differences between the games are some arrays. 
So what i want to do is when i click on the TableRow i want to change the values of some array's in an other java file. So i don't have to make an activity for each game but just one activity with changing values.

For game1 i want to have these arrays set in my games.java file:

```
int firstrow[] = { 2,  1, 2, 0} ;       
int secondrow[] = { 2,  2, 1, 2} ;          
int thirdrow[] = { 2,  0, 0, 2} ;           
int fourthrow[] = { 1,  2, 2, 2} ;   
int firstrowanswer[] = { 0, 1, 1, 0} ;  
int secondrowanswer[] = { 0, 0, 1, 1} ;     
int thirdrowanswer [] = { 1, 0, 0, 1} ;     
int fourthrowanswer[] = { 1, 1, 0, 0} ;
```

and for game2 for example

```
int firstrow[] = { 2,  0, 2, 1} ;       
int secondrow[] = { 2,  0, 2, 2} ;          
int thirdrow[] = { 0,  2, 2, 1} ;           
int fourthrow[] = { 0,  2, 2, 2} ;   
int firstrowanswer[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1} ;  
int secondrowanswer[] = { 1, 0, 1, 0} ;     
int thirdrowanswer [] = { 0, 1, 0, 1} ;     
int fourthrowanswer[] = { 0, 1, 1, 0} ;
```

How do i set the values of an array in an other file by clicking the tablerow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you pass those arrays as intent extras?

```
Intent gameActivity = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
gameActivity.putExtra("firstRow", arrayForFirstRow);
gameActivity.putExtra("secondRow", arrayForSecondRow);
...
startActivity(gameActivity);
```